# Play Framework using Spring data

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, spring-data-jpa, typesafe-activator

Using activator (play 2.0), I created a base java project.  I now want to start using jpa and spring data instead of ebean.  I added the following dependencies (taken from the typesafe-play-spring-data-jpa project) in to the build.sbt file, and when I run the project I see the spring data dependecies getting downloaded.

**build.sbt**

```
name := """my-project"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaCore,
  javaJpa,
  "org.springframework" % "spring-context" % "3.2.2.RELEASE",
  "javax.inject" % "javax.inject" % "1",
  "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-jpa" % "1.3.2.RELEASE",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "3.6.10.Final",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18",
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.9.5" % "test"
)
```

---

```
  [info] Resolving org.hibernate.javax.persistence#hibernate-jpa-2.0-api;1.0.1.Final ...
  [info] Resolving javax.inject#javax.inject;1 ...
  [info] Resolving org.springframework.data#spring-data-jpa;1.3.2.RELEASE ...
  [info] Resolving org.springframework.data#spring-data-commons;1.5.1.RELEASE ...
  [info] Resolving org.springframework#spring-orm;3.1.4.RELEASE ...
  [info] Resolving org.springframework#spring-jdbc;3.1.4.RELEASE ...
  [info] Resolving org.springframework#spring-tx;3.1.4.RELEASE ...
  [info] Resolving aopalliance#aopalliance;1.0 ...
  [info] Resolving org.springframework#spring-aop;3.1.4.RELEASE ...
  [info] Resolving org.springframework#spring-asm;3.1.4.RELEASE ...
  [info] Resolving org.aspectj#aspectjrt;1.7.2 ...
  [info] Resolving org.hibernate#hibernate-entitymanager;3.6.10.Final ...
  [info] Resolving org.hibernate#hibernate-core;3.6.10.Final ...
```

The issue I am having, is that when attempt to reference in Global.java

```
ctx.register(SpringDataJpaConfiguration.class);
```

I get error (in eclipse) stating that it cant find a reference to it.  I looked in the Referenced Libraries in eclipse, and I see the ref. to spring context, core and beans .... but no ref to spring data, which explains the error.

But why is the dependency not getting included in my project?

Thanks

Comment: Did you use the `reload` command in activator after you added the  `spring-data-jpa` dependency?

Comment: No effect - still the same results - missing the dependencies

Comment: Use ´dependencies` and see what happens when it tries to resolve that jar.  If it's there, then you maybe you need to run the `eclipse` command to re-generate the project files.

Comment: Getting much closer .... rerunning the eclipse command did the trick .. I now see the spring-data and related spring libs coming in.  However, eclipse still giving an error that SpringDataJpaConfiguration.class cant be found...

Am I missing a dependency?

Comment: If you can compile it in activator, then it's still an Eclipse-level issue (I'm an IntelliJ user, so I can't comment more on that) .

Comment: Never-mind my last comment ... that is my mistake ... thanks for your help .. now I can go to sleep :)

Comment: I'll write this up as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In activator:

1. Use the `reload` command after changing dependencies.
2. Use the `dependencies` command to ensure the dependencies can be resolved.
3. Use the `eclipse` command to re-generate the eclipse project, giving visibility of the new dependencies in the IDE.

I'm not sure if Eclipse can open sbt-based projects directly like IntelliJ can, but that's worth checking.